# In discord.py, How do I make a profanity filter

Tags: python, discord.py

This is what I have at the moment
and when I test it by typing a bad word in the list nothing happens. Why is this and what can code I use to fix it?

```py
infractions = {}
limit = 5
blacklist = ['bad words go here']
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content.lower()
    if any(word in content for word in blacklist):
        id = message.author.id
        infractions[id] = infractions.get(id, 0) + 1
        if infractions[id] >= limit:
            await bot.kick(message.author)
        else:
            warning = f"{message.author.mention} this is your {infractions[id]} warning"
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, warning)
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: you are using an old version of `discord.py`

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you are using an old version/tutorial of `discord.py`. Things like `bot.send_message` are out of date and things like `bot.kick` don't even exist.
The ideal code would be™:

```py
infractions = {}
limit = 5
blacklist = ['old', 'version', 'of', 'discord', '.', 'py']

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content.replace(' ', '')

    if any(word in content.lower() for word in blacklist):
        id = message.author.id
        infractions[id] = infractions.get(id, 0) + 1

        if infractions[id] >= limit:
            await message.author.kick()
        else:
            warning = f"{message.author.mention} this is your {infractions[id]} warning"
            await message.channel.send(warning)
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```